# Google calender Evolution sync no longer working

Tags: unity, sync, evolution, google-calendar

One of my favorite Unity features is when you click the date-time indicator it tells you upcoming events in your calender. I have evolution set up to sync with my Google Calender. I recently changed my google password and now when I click the indicator my upcoming events no longer show up. I opened up Evolution in order to change the password but now it takes approx. 3 mins to start up and when it does it freezes and i have to force quit it. Is there anyway to change the settings via some other application?

Answer (score 1):

I was using evolution calendar on my laptop when I was using Gnome-Shell and this kept happening to me. I had to actually remove the account from evolution calendar and add again it to make this stop happening. If you go to accounts you can delete your previous account and then just add it again and it should be fine.

[Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/05/14/connect-evolution-to-google-mail-and-calendar/) is some info on adding accounts if you need it.

Comment: You dont understand my problem. I cant open up evolution long enough before it freezes and stops responding